# Visual Studio Code windows , Python Pandas . No module named pandas

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, pandas, python-3.7

I set the variables for Env. All necessary modules for Pandas operation are installed by pip.
I wanted to run the code to display it in "Output". I run with: Alt + CTRL + N(or right click -> Run code).

[image]

In output returns the message:

[image]

But when I run in the terminal (right click -> Run Python File in Terminal), the code works correctly.

[image]

I would like the code to run correctly in output(right click -> Run code), not in the terminal.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the module *pandas* is installed in a virtual envorinment which you are not accessing via *VS Code*.

I'd suggest you to *install pandas* in default python as well via

```
pip install pandas
```

This way the VS Code will work it out just fine.

***Else:***

In **VS Code console**, *activate* the *virtual enviornment* in which you have installed the **pandas** module, and then *run* it. It should work

Comment: Its works. I installed pandas  in default Python and this is works. But why it does not work in a virtual environment ? Always activates the virtual environment before.

Comment: VS Code is not configured to use the virtual environment that you created. It could only use the default Python shell. That's why it was not working.

Comment: Well, I am glad to be of any help to you :) you can accept the answer so others may get helped also :) thanks

Comment: Thanks You for Your help. I must resolve problem with environment configuration in VS Code. For now I will be used default Python. Best regards:)

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem in VS Code. I was not able to find modules like Pandas, Selenium etc. Imports were underlined with a red colour.

Fixed the issue by changing the version of **Python** `3.7.3 64-bit` to version `3.8.1 64-bit`.

Procedure:

1. Hit `Ctrl + Shift + P`
2. Select Python: Select Interpreter
3. Choose the latest installed version of Python (no more red underlines)

Comment: I had to use F1 to open my command palette. Not sure why the other shortcut did not work.

Comment: This helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

@Davdei It is good practice to work with a virtual environment, so you can test against different versions of Python.
To get the list of available Python interpreter use (⇧⌘P) on Mac
or alternatively, you can click the status bar
[image: click the status bar]

Answer (score 3):

This can also happen when the specific module is not installed using pip3, so simply installing the module using pip3 would solve the problem.

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem and none of the above seems to solve the issue. Later found that it has to do something with the python interpreter. I created virtual environment and my terminal can see it, but not the python script file where the code exists. Therefore, it must be an interpreter problem. Changed the interpreter to correct location:

```
cd .venv/Scripts/
./activate
```

(Here ".venv" is my virtual environment name. It could be different too (eg. "venv")

With an existing installation via pip:

```
pip3 install pandas
```

This solved the problem.